# Validation Message - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validação

Olá, estou tentando aparecer a mensagem "validation" no ASP.NET no meu projeto 'CadeMeuMedico' pelo apostila Desenvolvimento Web com ASP.NET...

Porém, não está aparecendo como deveria aparecer conforme abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue os códigos:

Adicionar.cshtml (Pasta Views)

```
@model CadeMeuMedico.Models.Medicos

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
}

<h2>Adicionar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Medico</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CRM)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CRM)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CRM)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bairro)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bairro)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bairro)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AtendePorConvenio)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AtendePorConvenio)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AtendePorConvenio)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TemClinica)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TemClinica)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TemClinica)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WebSiteBlog)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WebSiteBlog)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WebSiteBlog)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cidades)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.DropDownList("IDCidade", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDCidade)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Especialidades)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("IDEspecialidade", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDEspecialidade)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
</div>
```

MedicosController (Pasta Controller)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CadeMeuMedico.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CadeMeuMedico.Controllers
{
    public class MedicosController : Controller
    {
        private CadeMeuMedicoBDEntities db = new CadeMeuMedicoBDEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Medicos/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var medicos = db.Medicos.Include(m => m.Cidades).Include(m => m.Especialidades).ToList();
            return View(medicos);
        }

        public ActionResult Adicionar()
        {
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome");
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Adicionar(Medicos medicos)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Medicos.Add(medicos);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome", medicos.IDCidade);
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome", medicos.IDEspecialidade);
            return View(medicos);

        }

    }
```

MedicoMetadado.cs (Pasta Models)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CadeMeuMedico.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MedicoMetadado))]
    public partial class Medico
    {

    }

    public class MedicoMetadado
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o CRM")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "O CRM deve possuir no máximo 30 caracteres")]
        public string CRM { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Nome")]
        [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "O Nome deve possuir no máximo 80 caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Endereço")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O Endereço deve possuir no máximo 100 caracteres")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Bairro")]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "O Bairro deve possuir no máximo 60 caracteres")]
        public string Bairro { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o E-mail")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O E-mail deve possuir no máximo 100 caracteres")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar se Atende por Convênio")]
        public bool AtendePorConvenio { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar se Tem Clínica")]
        public bool TemClinica { get; set; }

        [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "O Website deve possuir no máximo 80 caracteres")]
        public string WebsiteBlog { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar a Cidade")]
        public int IDCidade { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar a Especialidade")]
        public int IDEspecialidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Se vocês preferiem ver o meu github, segue o endereço abaixo:
https://github.com/joaowick/CadeMeuMedico

Conto com a sua ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é bem simples, você tem um classe de entidadade:

```
public partial class Medicos
```

e criou um classe `partial`:

```
public partial class Medico
```

Ou seja, não é a mesma classe da entidade, então coloque um `s` no final da classe que está faltando que vai resolver o problema para que você faça a referencia a mesma classe `Medicos`.

Comment: Olá, alterei e apareceu a mensagem de erro: O tipo de metadados associado ao tipo 'CadeMeuMedico.Models.Medicos' contém as seguintes propriedades ou campos desconhecidos: WebsiteBlog. Verifique se os nomes desses membros correspondem aos nomes das propriedades no tipo principal.

Comment: Então @JoaoTorresMoreira verifique se os models são igualzinhos...

Comment: O nome está diferente nas duas classes @JoaoTorresMoreira uma está WebsiteBlog e a outra WebSiteBlog tudo isso ele verifica

Comment: Puxa, que detalhe minima !!! Deu certo! Obrigado Virgilio!!